# Moving Immediate values to Floating Point Registers and performance issues

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm

I am trying to convert an ARM assembly code to use the Floating Point registers instead of ARM registers (due to performance issues I want to avoid push and pop to save the state of current registers.)

The following code will be added right before some ARM assembly instructions (to be accurate right before bl, blx, bx,b)

```
push {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4}
MOV     R2, #0x22
MOV     R1, #0x33
MUL     R3, R2, R1
movw    r4, #:lower16:Global
movt    r4, #:upper16:Global
movs    r2, #0
str     r2, [r4]
movs    r4, r3
pop {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4}
```

As you can see I am just doing some calculation. Prior to running b, bl, bx, blx.
However due to performance penalty (Which I guess it caused by push and pop) I want to avoid using push and pop. Instead I want to use floating point registers in ARM (using VFP 2.0 instructions).

Here is the first challenge I have. Can I copy immediate values to floating point registers in arm?

First of all I want to know if I can use VMOV to copy immediate values to Floating point registers. If yes, then can I use ARM commands to do mathematical operations over the floating point registers? If not then what are the alternatives for MUL,

```
VMOV    S2, #0x22
VMOV    S1, #0x33
VFMA    R3, S2, S1
movw    S4, #:lower16:Global
movt    S4, #:upper16:Global
movs    S2, #0
VSTR    S2, [S4]
movs    S4, S3
```

The conversion I made from ARM instruction to the VFP2.0 instruction set is incorrect.Since I can not find alternative instruction for movt and movs in VFP2.0

Is there any way that I can use floating point registers instead of the original ARM assembly codes to reduce the performance penalty. If yes, How I can convert the code correctly then?

I am using the Raspberry Pi (BCM 2835) platform.

More info about Floating Point instructions in ARM CPUs:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDHHAJF.html
https://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/vector-floating-point.php

Comment: Er, right there on the first page you linked to is ["Floating-point Move Immediate"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDJBCJG.html). Rick Murray's page is (as it says) about the ancient FPA, not VFP - you definitely don't want that.

Comment: Ah, My bad, You are right. I will remove that link :)

Comment: Furthermore, if I'm reading the question right, abusing the FPU to do integer maths is going to be _far_ more expensive than ~2 extra cycles to push+pop r4 to/from L1 cache (unless you're using some weird ABI, saving/restoring r0-r3 is completely unnecessary).

Comment: @Notlikethat Actually the final goal is not to do mathematical calculation. I am making control flow monitoring system. Because my memory dispatcher function is not yet ready I used the mathematical operations to calculate the near performance overhead. In reality I just move the data of a register (e.g. LR ) to the FP registers and then copy it to my memory dispatcher function.